# Socket closed when running all the fitnesse test but not independently

Tags: jenkins, fitnesse-slim

When I try to run my fitnesse tests they pass independantely. But when I'm trying to launch all of them at once it freeze, at the third test of the second suite, and in jenkins (where it can timeout), I get the following error :

```
17:56:05 Output stream closed unexpectedly (Stop button pressed?) [Relais brisé (pipe)]
17:56:16 SEVERE: Killing slim client as exception occurred:fitnesse.slim.SlimError: Got invalid slim header from client. Read the following: HTTP/1.1 408 Request Time-out
17:56:16 WARNING: Failed to kill SLiM client [Socket closed]
17:56:16 java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
17:56:16    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:116)
17:56:16    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
17:56:16    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
17:56:16    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
17:56:16    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:158)
17:56:16    at fitnesse.testsystems.slim.SlimCommandRunningClient.kill(SlimCommandRunningClient.java:81)
17:56:16    at fitnesse.testsystems.slim.SlimTestSystem.exceptionOccurred(SlimTestSystem.java:206)
17:56:16    at fitnesse.testsystems.slim.SlimTestSystem.processTable(SlimTestSystem.java:126)
17:56:16    at fitnesse.testsystems.slim.HtmlSlimTestSystem.processAllTablesOnPage(HtmlSlimTestSystem.java:48)
17:56:16    at fitnesse.testsystems.slim.SlimTestSystem.runTests(SlimTestSystem.java:101)
17:56:16    at fitnesse.testrunner.MultipleTestsRunner.executeTestSystemPages(MultipleTestsRunner.java:171)
17:56:16    at fitnesse.testrunner.MultipleTestsRunner.startTestSystemAndExecutePages(MultipleTestsRunner.java:89)
17:56:16    at fitnesse.testrunner.MultipleTestsRunner.internalExecuteTestPages(MultipleTestsRunner.java:77)
17:56:16    at fitnesse.testrunner.MultipleTestsRunner.executeTestPages(MultipleTestsRunner.java:63)
17:56:16    at fitnesse.responders.run.SuiteResponder.performExecution(SuiteResponder.java:306)
17:56:16    at fitnesse.responders.run.SuiteResponder.doExecuteTests(SuiteResponder.java:139)
17:56:16    at fitnesse.responders.run.SuiteResponder.doSending(SuiteResponder.java:117)
17:56:16    at fitnesse.responders.ChunkingResponder.startSending(ChunkingResponder.java:70)
17:56:16    at fitnesse.http.ChunkedResponse.sendTo(ChunkedResponse.java:25)
17:56:16    at fitnesse.FitNesseExpediter.sendResponse(FitNesseExpediter.java:102)
17:56:16    at fitnesse.FitNesseExpediter.start(FitNesseExpediter.java:52)
17:56:16    at fitnesse.FitNesseServer.serve(FitNesseServer.java:28)
17:56:16    at fitnesse.FitNesseServer.serve(FitNesseServer.java:21)
17:56:16    at fitnesse.socketservice.SocketService$ServerRunner.run(SocketService.java:122)
17:56:16    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17:56:16 SEVERE: Killing slim client as exception occurred:java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
```

The test that block the suite have nothing particular, in fact it passed before, it pass when launched alone, and I did not touch it at all.

I had the opposite problem previousely "A single test is not working but when you launch all the test at once they pass". It was caused by some tests's name that were not WikiWord. So now all my test's name are wikiword.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused by a timeout exception (changed the default value for something higher and it now works). I cannot really explain why it took longer when passing all the test, maybe because as it's longer, I was starting to do something else on the computer and was using CPU time and resources.